# What is the use of return this["key"]?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

This is an simple Scenario , i totally understand the first code of set & get.

```
    private string exampleValue;

    public string Example
    {
         get { return this.exampleValue ;  }
         set { this.exampleValue = value ; }
    }
```

How is it differ from this code :

```
    public string Example 
    {
       get 
       { 
         return this["Example"].ToString();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Look for [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx) and [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: Any sample example can you share ?

Comment: Hard to answer if we don't know what `this` is. 2nd form uses an indexer, it may be useful to store properties in a dictionary-like object and also to provide a typed shortcut for common use properties (with a _normal_ property syntax). Why properties should be stored in a dictionary? Depends on context and implementation (first example comes to my mind is a poor-man `DependencyProperty` like implementation).

Comment: Well for a start, the second block of code won't compile unless `Example` derives from an indexable type e.g. `Dictionary<T, K>`. Classes aren't just indexable out of the box, but you can [make them indexable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx). Without any context the question is unanswerable, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) property.

You can define your own indexers in a class. For example, here is a string indexer.

```
class myClass
{
    ...

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            ... implement code here to retrieve the object that correspond to your string index
        }
        set
        {
            ... implement code here to store the object that correspond to your string index
        }
    }
}
```

Indexers are not limited to string or integer. For example, the Dictionary object uses a generic Indexer:

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ...
...
public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

Also, the `Session` and `Application` objects in ASP.NET uses a string indexer.